# C# datagridview cell value edit is undone after changing current cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I hope you can help me. I didn't find a solution which fits my problem by googling.

I have a DataGridView with no bound data. When the user double-clicks in a cell he can write a new value into the cell. Based on the change, the value in the neighbour-cell is changed too. This is working properly so far.

Now I want to set some conditions, like thresholds and if the user is out of the range the value in the edited cell should be corrected.
The value in the neighbour-cell is still calculated right, but the value in the user-edited cell always stays at the user input value.

I already tried several combinations of BeginEdit() and CurrentCell..., but always the same.

Here is my actual code for the cellvalueChanged Event:

```
private void dgSpotInfo_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cellvaluechangend)
        {
            cellvaluechangend = false;

            int mod_Int_index = dgSpotInfo.Columns.IndexOf(dgSpotInfo.Columns["col_modifiedIntensity"]);

            dgSpotInfo.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
            dgSpotInfo.BeginEdit(true);
            int val;

            if (e.ColumnIndex == mod_Int_index) // if the modified Intensity value is changed
            {
                val = (Convert.ToInt32(dgSpotInfo[mod_Int_index, e.RowIndex].Value) - Convert.ToInt32(spot_analysis.GetFoundSpots[e.RowIndex].ModifiedIntensity));

                // here is tested if the value is too high

                if (Convert.ToInt32(dgSpotInfo[mod_Int_index, e.RowIndex].Value) > 255)
                {
                    // here is the problem, during debugging the value is displayed right, 
                    // but afterwards the current cell it is displayed as the too high value again

                    dgSpotInfo[mod_Int_index, e.RowIndex].Value = "255";
                    val = (Convert.ToInt32(dgSpotInfo[mod_Int_index, e.RowIndex].Value) - Convert.ToInt32(spot_analysis.GetFoundSpots[e.RowIndex].ModifiedIntensity));
                }

                dgSpotInfo.CurrentCell = dgSpotInfo[modifier_index, e.RowIndex];
                dgSpotInfo[modifier_index, e.RowIndex].Value = Convert.ToString(val);
            }

            dgSpotInfo.EndEdit();
            dgSpotInfo.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2;

            dgSpotInfo.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
```

and here for my clicking event:

```
        private void dgSpotInfo_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Testing if the clicked cell is allowed to change
        if (((e.ColumnIndex == dgSpotInfo.Columns.IndexOf(dgSpotInfo.Columns["col_modifiedIntensity"])) || (e.ColumnIndex == dgSpotInfo.Columns.IndexOf(dgSpotInfo.Columns["col_Modifier"]))) && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            dgSpotInfo.CurrentCell = dgSpotInfo[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            dgSpotInfo.ReadOnly = false;
            dgSpotInfo.BeginEdit(true);
            cellvaluechangend = true;
        } 
    }
```

I hope I descriped my problem understandable and you can help me.
Tanks!

Comment: can you try e.Cancel = true; in event

Comment: what do you mean? my current events don't have this property. Should I use a CancelEvent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has a similar problem: 
I solved the problem by adding a CellEndEdit event. After the user edited the cell I am doing the threshold validation like above now in the CellEndEdit event handler. I don't know why, but maybe it is so, that in the event handler which is caused by the editing you cannot undo the editing.